# WAR on tomcat cannot find deploy.jar in jre

Tags: java, tomcat

I have deployed my application on Tomcat as a WAR file. At one point I am using URLEncoder from com.sun.deploy.net to encode HTTP GET parameters.

```
message = URLEncoder.encode(message);
```

This compiles just fine. But as soon as the deployed application tries to access this method I receive a

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.deploy.net.URLEncoder
```

Why is that? I understand that the URLEncoder class belongs to `deploy.jar` of the JRE since java 1.3 (I am using 1.7) but Tomcat doesn't seem to find it ...

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just being incredibly stupid

It should have been

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
```

rather than `import com.sun.deploy.net.URLEncoder;` which is just plain wrong. Now it works, of course!

Comment: absolutely **never** use any class inside of `com.sun.` - all of these are deprecated or even obsolete, they exist for compatibility reasons and sometimes a replacement has yet to created. Using any of these will always result in unexpected behaviour. Prefer using a third-part lib over using the sun-classes **if** there is no replacement or alternative - almost all classes have alternatives nowadays.